# OpenMP uderstanding deadlock in critical construct

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, critical-section

I am trying to understand exactly why a deadlock occurs when in a parallel region a critical construct is nested in a critical construct.

I have consulted the following resources: [this](http://www.mathe.tu-freiberg.de/files/personal/253/high-performance-computing-ws2014-slides-2-openmp-gdb-gprof.pdf) source the author writes:

> In OpenMP this can happen if inside a critical region a function is called which
>   contains another critical region. In this case the critical region of the called
>   function will wait for the first critical region to terminate - which will never
>   happen.

Alright, but why not? Furthermore from: Hager, Georg, and Gerhard Wellein. Introduction to high performance computing for scientists and engineers. CRC Press, 2010, p. 149:

> When a thread encounters a CRITICAL directive inside a critical region, it will block forever.

Same question, why?

Finally, Chapman, Barbara, Gabriele Jost, and Ruud Van Der Pas. Using OpenMP: portable shared memory parallel programming. Vol. 10. MIT press, 2008 also provide an example using locks, however not with the critical construct.

From my current understanding there are two different possible ways why a deadlock occurs in a nested critical region:

Begin first take:

If two threads arrive at a nested critical construct (one critical region inside another), thread one enters the "outer" critical region and thread two waits. Quoting Chapman et al.

> When a thread encounters a critical construct, it waits until no other thread is
>   executing a critical region with the same name.

Alright, so far so good. Now, thread one DOES NOT enter the nested critical region, because it is a synchronization point where threads wait for all other threads to arrive before proceeding. And since the second thread is waiting for the first thread the exit the "outer" critical region they are in a deadlock.

End first take.

Begin second take:

Both threads arrive at the "outer" critical construct. Thread one enters the "outer" critical construct, thread two waits. Now, thread one ENTERS the "inner" critical construct and stops at it's implied barrier, because it waits for thread two. Thread two on the other hand waits for thread one to exit to "outer" thread and so both are waiting forever.

End second take.

Here is a small Fortran code that produces the deadlock:

```
  1   subroutine foo
  2 
  3     !$OMP PARALLEL 
  4     !$OMP CRITICAL 
  5       print*, 'Hallo i am just a single thread and I like it that way'
  6     !$OMP END CRITICAL
  7     !$OMP END PARALLEL 
  8 
  9   end subroutine foo
 10 
 11 program deadlock
 12   implicit none
 13   integer :: i,sum = 0
 14 
 15   !$OMP PARALLEL
 16   !$OMP DO 
 17   do i = 1, 100
 18   !$OMP CRITICAL
 19      sum = sum + i
 20      call foo()
 21   !$OMP END CRITICAL
 22   enddo
 23   !$OMP END DO
 24   !$OMP END PARALLEL
 25 
 26   print*, sum
 27 end program deadlock
```

So my question is, is one of the two suggestions right, or is there another possibility
why a deadlock occurs in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no implied barrier, i.e. no "synchronization point where threads wait for other threads to *arrive*" associated with CRITICAL constructs.  Instead, at the start of a critical construct, threads wait for any thread *already inside* a critical construct of the same name to *leave* the construct.

Critical constructs *with the same name* cannot be nested, because the current OpemMP rules say they can not (see the restrictions on nesting in OpemMP 4.0 section 2.16).  That's really the answer to your question and the end of the discussion - if you break that prohibition then anything can happen.

Practically, this prohibition allows implementations to assume that critical constructs with the same name will not be nested.  One common implementation choice is then that a thread encountering a critical construct will wait for all threads **including itself** to leave the construct.  If it is waiting a thread cannot be leaving.  That results in a deadlock.

Critical constructs with different names can be nested.  Deadlock is possible in that case if the nesting is not consistent.  Consider:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL

!$OMP CRITICAL (A)
!$OMP CRITICAL (B)      ! Thread one waiting here.
!...
!$OMP OMP CRITICAL (B)
!$OMP END CRITICAL (A)

!$OMP CRITICAL (B)
!$OMP CRITICAL (A)      ! Thread two waiting here.
!...
!$OMP OMP CRITICAL (A)
!$OMP END CRITICAL (B)

!$END PARALLEL
```

If this situation occurs the threads will be waiting quite a while.

Comment: A small follow up question to your explanation: so when thread one is entering the "outer" critical region then thread two waits outside. Now thread one is waiting for "any" thread to leave the "inner" critical region, which does not happen because only one thread at a time can enter the "outer" critical region. So it is waiting for itself to leave. Is that correctly interpreted?

Comment: I changed one word relevant to your follow up - 'any' to 'all' for correctness.  A plausible implementation is that, when it strikes the inner critical construct, thread one (atomically) queries whether the critical section has a thread inside it.  The answer is yes, so the thread waits.  (If the answer was no, the thread would (atomically with the query) flag that the critical section was occupied and proceed into the section.)  The thread ends up waiting for itself.  Thread two is irrelevant - it could be waiting at the outer construct boundary, or be off flying to the moon.